Downloadable AI visual+sound bots from bot launcher app
I am looking for a downloadable AI visual+sound boots from bot launcher app.
The app displays a set of icons, with images. On each image, the image of a bot, which is programmed and uploaded to a website from which the icons are downloaded.
Inside the app, you can view play, on click on the launchers to insert a bot.
The bot interacts via sound and image (as it moves and makes sounds), while interacting on-screen with the other AI bots.
The website has a variety of rooms that have our allow or cater to different styles of programming the bots and you can connect to the website from chrome logging in as a bot developer (program a bot) or as a room developer (program room rules).
You can then connect via the Android app and retrieve a room and download different bots (the one compatible with the room rules), and view and listen to them interact.
Where is this available?
Has this been implemented?
Is anyone willing to do so?
Thanks
